# magento product custom options

Tags: php, magento

We have an install of Magento running a number of sites for a travel company. The sites include a UK, US, European and South African store as well as a number of white label sites. The products within each store are the same with a number of them having a custom option set up for "Travel Date".

We've decided we'd like to make some dates unavailable from some sites whilst still being available for others. So for example the date '20th November 2014' would be available for users booking in the US or UK but not South Africa.

Selecting the correct 'Store View' from the top of the left hand column within a product, then selecting 'Custom Options' shows me the custom options for that product but removing one option removes it globally. Does anyone know if there's a way to remove a custom option for one store without removing it from the product completely?

Comment: This isn't easy, I would buy a module -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've ended up using a bit of a .js hack to get the result I wanted...  (I'm not sure how to post code in a comment but will answer my own post with the solution)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was the following:

```
    j$("#select_9 option[value='128']").hide();
j$("#select_9 option[value='128']").attr("disabled","disabled");
```